# Drupal или Joomla, а может другая CMS?

Tags: drupal, joomla, cms

Хочу сделать портал, но не знаю, на каком движке. Планирую сделать форум, блог, который будут вести люди, ну и сам материал по теме сайта. Знания почти нулевые, ну это не большая беда.

Answer (score 2):

Хз друпал вроде интереснее смотрится, хотя не вникал.. джумлу однозначно не рекомендую.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше всего собственный, а по вашей ситуации - joomla.

Answer (score 0):

я бы тоже посоветовал Joomla

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [InstantCMS](http://www.instantcms.ru/)

Answer (score 0):

Друпал однозначно. В нем все понятно и документации куча